# 64-bit Windows 7 Recursive directory removal fails when deleting a directory containing Sqlite

Tags: sqlite, fileapi

I have a test case (stripped version of bigger application) which fails sporadically on Windows 7 machine when trying to remove directory or file. It is using native Windows APIs.
Test performs following steps --

1. Create directory.
2. Create a sqlite3 db in the directory created by step#1.
3. Create a table in the DB.
4. Close the DB.
5. If any DB journal file is present, delete it.
6. Delete the DB file.
7. Delete the directory.

If you skip step#1, then test would run fine.
If you add delay between step#4 and step#5, then test would run fine.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <direct.h>
#include <sqlite3.h>
#include <io.h>
using namespace std;

bool sleep_for_sometime = false;
bool create_table = false;
bool runTest()
{
    char cwdpath[1024] = {'\0'};
    if (_getcwd(cwdpath, 1023) == NULL) return false;
    string testpath(cwdpath);
    testpath += "/test_dir";
    _mkdir(testpath.c_str());
    string dbpath = testpath + "/test.db";
    sqlite3 *db = NULL;
    if (sqlite3_open(dbpath.c_str(), &db) != SQLITE_OK) return false;
    // Create table.
    if (create_table) {
        string sql = "CREATE TABLE COMPANY(" \
                  "ID INT PRIMARY KEY  NOT NULL," \
                  "NAME           TEXT NOT NULL," \
                  "AGE            INT  NOT NULL)";
        char *zErrMsg = 0;
        if (sqlite3_exec(db, sql.c_str(), NULL, 0, &zErrMsg) != SQLITE_OK) {
            sqlite3_close(db);
            cerr << "Could not create table: " << zErrMsg << endl;
            return false;
        }
    }
    sqlite3_close(db);
    if (sleep_for_sometime) {
        Sleep(100);
    }
    string journal_file = dbpath + "-journal";
    string journal_error = journal_file + " failed";
    if (_access(journal_file.c_str(), 06) == 0) {
        if (_unlink(journal_file.c_str()) != 0) {
            perror(journal_error.c_str());
            return false;
        }
        cout << "journal file --" << journal_file << endl;
    }
    string db_error = dbpath + " failed";
    if (_unlink(dbpath.c_str()) != 0) {
       perror(db_error.c_str());
       return false;
    }
    string dir_error = testpath + " failed";
    if (_rmdir(testpath.c_str()) != 0) {
       perror(dir_error.c_str());
       return false;
    }
    return true;
}
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    cout << "Usage: ./projtest 1 1" << endl;
    cout << "------If you pass two parameter, then always create table and sleep for some time." << endl;
    cout << "Usage: ./projtest 1" << endl;
    cout << "------If you pass one parameter, then always create table, but don't sleep." << endl;
    cout << "Usage: ./projtest" << endl;
    cout << "------If you don't pass any parameter, then don't create table and don't sleep." << endl;
    if (argc == 3) {
      sleep_for_sometime = true;
      create_table = true;
    } else if (argc == 2) {
      create_table = true;
      sleep_for_sometime = false;
    } else {
      create_table = false;
      sleep_for_sometime = false;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 500 ; i++) {
        if (! runTest()) {
            cerr << "Err in runTest trial --" << i+1 << endl;
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be that the active filelock sqllite imposes it not cleared in time betweens step 4 and 5.
Remember your code in memory runs at flash speed compared to a harddisk.
The sql lite process instructions to harddisk is probaly still busy writing data to the file, entering entries in the log, then releasing the file handler whilst your code is already busy wanting it removed.

So whilst sql lite is done and dealth with, the harddisk is still ticking off its work list of writing the data and clearing the locks.

Maybe you could implement a while loop that checks if the file is locked and then patiently waits for the lock to be released,or mark the file for future deletion and recheck every 50ms.

**edit**
added clarification

The thing is there are two issues here. hard disk speed and CPU speed. In normal program code when you push a write instruction to the hard disk it is put in a queue in the driver/drive itself for writing and the driver/harddisk works off the que one by one(ish).

The program will have received a message that the operation has been comitted so it can continue executing. Why should a program have to wait a millisecond or two before continueing right? Since the hard drive is slow and has its own priorities of reading stuff and writing stuff. it will do it but just not exactly now cause its now reading a file or something.

So whilst the write operation that the file is free to edit is still in the queue to be written it already sends a delete request but the file has not been marked as writeable yet because that operation is still in the queue. And there the error comes from.

Comment: This code is single threaded, so why should sqlite3_close() return before completing all this operation. Secondly, [default synchronous pragma option value is FULL](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_synchronous). It means that When synchronous is FULL (2), the SQLite database engine will use the xSync method of the VFS to ensure that all content is safely written to the disk surface prior to continuing. So, control should never return until everything is property written into the disk.

Comment: I added a little clarification. It might be so that the file itself is fully written, but that the same priciples dont apply to the file lock that was applied.

Comment: I also observed similar problem in following type of situation.     `DeleteFile('xyz'); fopen('xyz', 'w')`. Here file open fails with permission denied. It is not always reproducible, but many time it is reproducible.

Comment: It is basically the same problem as here. It would be best to see the hard drive instructions and your program as seperate processes. When your program gives a delete instruction to the drive process the drive process will add to queue, finish jobs, then lock file, mark FS registry that file is deleted and clear lock. If you try to open the file too soon after delete lock is applied you should get a permission denied. Its a good thing. You should not be able to write to a file marked for deletion. Use timestamped names to get around this issue